# TLS 1.3 not working on nginx 1.21 with openssl 1.1.1n

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

I have nginx (1.21.6) running with openssl 1.1.1n on a Debian 11 server.
Although I followed many tutorials and looked at multiple questions in this forum about this topic, I can't get TLS 1.3 working.
The output of `nginx -V`:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.21.6
built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021 (running with OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022)
TLS SNI support enable
```

I upgraded nginx to the mainline version because I wasn't able to get TLS 1.3 working in previous versions, too. It's very strange...
Openssl definitely supports TLS 1.3. I tested it via `openssl s_client -tls1_3 -connect www.cloudflare.com:443` which worked well.
Here my `ssl.conf` file of nginx which I included in each of my nginx servers (certificates are included separately in the server sections):

```
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_stapling on;
#ssl_trusted_certificate /pfad/bundle.ca.pem;
ssl_stapling_verify on;

ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

ssl_ecdh_curve X448:secp521r1:secp384r1;


ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS13-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;preload;includeSubDomains" always;
```

The [Qualys ssltest of my sites](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=aaron%2dschaal.de&hideResults=on&latest) doesn't however show that I use TLS 1.3 on my server. Also, Chrome browser shows that it connects via TLS 1.2.
Even if I remove the `TLSv1.2` directive from my `ssl.conf` and leaving only `TLSv1.3`, it connects still via TLS 1.2.

There is nowhere else a `ssl_protocols`directive in any other configuration file of nginx. I checked that via `nginx -T`.

I am really running out off ideas.....
Can anyone help me?

**EDIT:**
Somehow, nginx doesn't seem to react on the `ssl_protocols` and the `ssl_ecdh_curve` directive properly. E.g., when I delete the `ssl_ciphers` from my configuration (as @drookie suggested in his comment), TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 seem to be supported by my server although I set `ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;`. Similarly, according to [Qualys ssltest](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=aaron%2dschaal.de&hideResults=on&latest), `secp256r1` is supported, although I don't have this curve in my configuration of `ssl_ecdh_curve` (nor `prime256v1`). It seems to me as if something overwrites my settings in the `ssl.conf` file.
I am using acme.sh for getting my certificates.
`grep -R 'ssl_protocol' /etc/*` only gives the line in `ssl.conf` with `ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;`.
I have no idea what could cause the interference/overwriting...

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: What does nginx -t report?

Comment: @Robert Longson `nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich: I only see errors coming from the SSLTest from qualys, indicating that some handshakes are not successful: `[crit] 94566#94566: *34 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14201044:SSL routines:tls_choose_sigalg:internal error) while SSL handshaking, client: 64.41.200.113, server: 0.0.0.0:443`.
Even in debug mude, there are no further SSL errors displayed when I access the site.

Comment: another error coming from Qualys ssltest `[info] 47207#47207: *206 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher) while SSL handshaking, client: 64.41.200.114, server: 0.0.0.0:443`. But I guess that's normal

Comment: Revove `ssl_ciphers`, try defaults for starters. You may merely lack the cipher for the TLS 1.3.

Comment: @drookie Removing `ssl_ciphers`strangely yields the server to accept TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1, but not TLS 1.3! Very interesting that it seems to ignore the `ssl_protocols`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many further tests and much reading, I finally found a solution.
I had to write the ssl configuration in the `http` block, not in the `server` blocks of my nginx configuration. This worked, however, only if I copy the directives from my `ssl.conf` file explicitly to the `http` block in my `nginx.conf` (otherwise `nginx -t` outputs

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "include" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:33
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

for some reason).

Hence, my `http` block of `nginx.conf` looks now as follows:

```
http {

  ...
 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;
    
    ssl_ecdh_curve X448:secp521r1:secp384r1;
    
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers 'TLS-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256';

   ...

    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I don't know why these ssl settings have to be included/pasted in the `http` block rather than in each `server` block.....
But it works and TLS 1.3 is enabled!

Comment: My development environment is similar to yours  (nginx 1.21.6 + openssl v1.1.1c + Debian 10) but in my case `ssl_protocols` in server block works normally without issue. did you download  the latest commits of nginx v1.21.6 ? I think your nginx has some bugs which has been fixed after the time you downloaded it .

Comment: @Ham Yes , you're right ! I have just tested it again right now and it works also when `ssl_protocols`is in the `server`blocks. Thanks! Obviously, the bug has been fixed!

Comment: @phonon112358 I'm having similar problem. Ham says "did you download the latest commits of nginx v1.21.6" I'm not sure to understand,1.21.6 is 1.21.6, commites over 1.21.6 would be a newer version.  What have changed in your setup since last year ? Could you send output of nginx -V again ?